# Terraform aws_iam_role_policy This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not provide permissions

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

I created an "aws_iam_role_policy" resource for granting access to CloudWatch MSK metrics. I created an output to collect the ARN for the MSK cluster because I had to restrict the access to specific MSK cluster only. However I ran into permission error after I applied it when I was testing by aws kafka list-clusters --region $REGION. 
**An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListClusters operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxx:assumed-role/my-instance-role/xxxxxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: kafka:ListClusters on resource: arn:aws:kafka:us-west-2:xxxxxx:/v1/clusters**

 And I also see the warning **This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition.** for this msk_access policy on AWS Console. Did I miss any actions or sth. else?

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "msk_access" {
  name = "${element(split("-", var.product), 0)}-${var.env}-${var.region}-msk-access"
  role = module.instance_role.instance_role

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "kafka:Describe*",
                "kafka:List*",
                "kafka:Get*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "${data.terraform_remote_state.msk_vpc[0].outputs.cluster_arn}"
        }
    ]
}
EOF

}
```

Comment: Did you check what's the actual `Resource` part of your IAM policy in the AWS console?

Comment: What exactly is `data.terraform_remote_state.msk_vpc`?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki Yes. The resource was a MSK cluster. I think the issue here was that I used the output to give the msk cluster ARN as resource as I had to restrict access at cluster level, however I lost the permission to run aws kafka list-clusters. But I needed to be able to run list-clusters for a shell script to parse the name of the msk cluster. If I replaced "${data.terraform_remote_state.msk_vpc[0].outputs.cluster_arn}" by *, it worked, but is there a way not to use * here?

Comment: @Marcin terraform_remote_state data source retrieves the root module output values from other configuration, using the latest state snapshot from the remote backend, in my case, it retrieves my msk cluster information.